# What is the concept of a limit in simple terms

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm 14 just starting high school and I got interested in all the new math so I took a little dive into calculus but I can't wrap my head around the concept of a limit and for which uses it is applied to an equation and when I should use a limit.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are asking for the equivalent of a couple of weeks' worth of Calculus lectures, which is not what this website is suited for. But do look for earlier questions tagged *limits*, as you may find some to be useful.

Comment: To get an intuitive explanation, I recommend 3b1b 's [Essence of Calculus](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr)

Comment: Using limits is **a way to deal with infinity** (there are others...). A very simple case : if I consider the sequence of numbers $0.9, 0.99, 0.999, 0.9999 \cdots$, its limit is $1$, and this is a correct way to say that $0.99999...$ with an "infinity of decimals" is in fact $1$, this "infinity of decimals" arguing being questionable... (I could have written neatly this issue as $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-\tfrac{1}{10^n})=1$).

Answer (score 0):

In many situations, we want to evaluate a function at a point where it's not defined. In some of these situations the limit, if it exists, is a good candidate for that value. Let me illustrate with a few examples.

As in Jean Marie's example in the comments, often the function is defined at positive integers and we want to know what happens "at infinity". In the specific example, think of the function that takes $n$ to $$0.\underbrace{999\dots9}_n = 1 - \frac{1}{10^n}.$$ As $n$ gets bigger this quantity gets arbitrarily close to $1$, so we define the expression $0.999\dots$ with "infinitely many" $9$'s to be the $1$, which is precisely the limit of $1 - 1/10^n$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$. This is also how limits of sequences and infinite series work.

Here's another example where the details are harder to check but the idea using a limit is similar. Suppose you know that the circumference of a unit circle (a circle with radius $1$) is $2\pi$ and want to find its area. If you divide up the circle into $n$ equal sectors, then for large $n$ each is approximately a triangle with base $\approx \frac{2\pi}{n}$ and height $\approx 1$. So the total area of these sectors is $\approx n \times \frac12 \times \frac{2\pi}{n} \times 1 = \pi$. As $n$ gets large the approximations get better and the limit is exactly $\pi$.

Sometimes, instead of integer inputs, the functions is defined near some value $a$, but not at exactly $a$. This is the case in the calculus definition of tangents (or derivatives). Consider the graph of $y = x^3$, and the secant line joining the point $(0, 0)$ to another point $(t, t^3)$ on this graph. As long as $t \ne 0$, this line is uniquely defined and has slope $t^3/t = t^2$. But if $t = 0$, the point $(t, t^3)$ is the same as $(0, 0)$, so there isn't a *unique* line joining them. But it's clear, either from this calculation of the slope or visually, that for $t$ near $0$, the secant line gets arbitrarily close to being horizontal. The tangent line therefore should be horizontal, ie have slope $0 = \lim_{t \to 0} t^2$.

Another useful (but again harder) example is the definition of $10^x$ for real $x$. For positive integer $x$ this can be defined by repeated multiplication, and then it extends to negative integers and rational $x$ by extrapolating the rule $10^{x + y} = 10^x \times 10^y$. Then we can define the value $10^x$ at irrational $x$ to be
$$\lim_{\substack{y \to x\\ y \in \mathbb{Q}}} 10^y ,$$
ie the limit of $10^y$ as $y$ approaches $x$ through rationals, where we have already defined $10^y$. This is not the only way to extend the definition of exponentiation to real exponents, but it always involves taking limits in some sense.